# How to show in a row images and texts in PHP using bootstrap columns?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

Wanting to show the images and text for example in 5 lines within the same column but in the code presented this does not do what I want because these when they are shown are showing in lines instead of columns. I would appreciate your help.

This image shows what is currently shows on screen...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbELm.jpg

What I want is this...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3fv9.jpg

```
<?php
    $select_stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM galeria ORDER BY id DESC;" );  //sql select query
    $select_stmt->execute();
    while($row=$select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-6"><img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" class="imagem" style="height: 100px; weight: 100px;"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"><a id=""><?php echo $row['texto'];?></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Do not create container for every rows.. :-)

Comment: Your design is going to be a little more complicated because you are trying to create 5 columns within Bootstrap's 12 column grid. You will have to write an empty `.col-sm-1` at the beginning and end of every group of five `.col-sm-2` elements.

Comment: I said it should be 5 but it could be other values in this case or 2, 3 or 4.

Answer (score 1):

Now it is working. Thanks to all of you for your help. This is the code working below.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<?php
    $select_stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM galeria ORDER BY id DESC;" );  //sql select query
    $select_stmt->execute();
    while($row=$select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
?>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="col-sm-12"><img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" class="imagem" style="height: 100px; weight: 100px;"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12"><a id=""><?php echo $row['texto'];?></a></div>
        </div>

<?php
}
?>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to build the items with each image. The container remains outside the cycle.

```
    <div class="container">

    <?php
        $select_stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM galeria ORDER BY id DESC;" );  //sql select query
        $select_stmt->execute();
        while($row=$select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
    ?>
<div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12"><img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" class="imagem" style="height: 100px; weight: 100px;"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-12"><a id=""><?php echo $row['texto'];?></a></div>
            </div>
</div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: i change want you sugested and didn't work. Stay the same

Comment: i did try your change and didn't work and you can see on inspector this to.
https://imgur.com/a/hadiQzP

Comment: You are using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You should not create one container per row. Only one container which contain all rows 
Change your code to this :

```
<div class="container">
<?php
    $select_stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM galeria ORDER BY id DESC;" );  //sql select query
    $select_stmt->execute();
    while($row=$select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-6"><img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" class="imagem" style="height: 100px; weight: 100px;"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"><a id=""><?php echo $row['texto'];?></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>


<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: i change want you sugested and didn't work. Stay the same

Comment: What do you see in chrome or firefox dom inspector ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your help. I did get this to work and i will show you all.

Answer (score 0):

my way

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <a href="/images/<?php echo... 

      </div>
```

or

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;">

    <a href="/images/<?php echo...

        </div>
```